# Sort table in Angular component

Tags: angular, sorting, angular-material

I have two Angular components, one is the whole page which loads another component which is just a table.

[image: vs code screenshot]

The table is loaded through
`<app-detections-table [dataSource]="dataSource"></app-detections-table>`
in `detections.component.html`.
In `detections-table.component.html` I've added

```
<table
mat-table
[dataSource]="dataSource"
#sort
matSort="sort"
>
```

and `<th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header>Name</th>` to each of the column headers.
In `detections-table.component.ts` I added

```
  ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
```

Now, I get the sorting arrows on the table, but nothing happens when I click them.
If I remove passing in the dataSource from `detections.component.html` to the table component and just use a JSON objec in the table component then it works as expected, so I assume that sorting in `detections-table.component.ts` is "too late", which is why I tried adding `this.dataSource.sort = this.sort` to the end of `ngOnInit()` in `detections.component.ts`, but that also didn't do anything.
Anybody got a tip? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem with mat-table and i solved it by using a setter on the @Input and load the table properties in a separate function.

```
tableData = new MatTableDataSource([]);

@Input() set dataSource(value: any[]) {
    if(value) {
    this.loadTable(value);
    }
}
```

And for the loadTable you could do something like this:

```
loadTable(data: any[]) {
    this.tableData = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    this.tableData.sort = this.sort;
}
```

In this example the "tableData" variable becomes the datasource that you use for the table so this:

```
<table
mat-table
[dataSource]="dataSource"
#sort
matSort="sort"
>
```

Would become this:

```
<table
mat-table
[dataSource]="tableData"
#sort
matSort="sort"
>
```

Hopefully this solves your issue!